# why gcov total files count is varying?

Tags: gcov

We are using gcov and lcov for code coverage. After installing a instrumented build we see 5060 gcno files. when we run a test we see around 4687 gcda files. Each test run shows different number of gcda files. Though our build has 5060 files why each test run shows different number of total files as shown below?:

```
Test1% = 2808(covered files)/4883(total files) 
Test2% = 2501(covered files)/4811(total files)
```

Why my code coverage output varying total files for each test run? Can we make it constant so our coverage calculations are meaningful/proper.

Comment: Do you have any nondeterminism in the runs, like relying on random number generators or implicit dependencies on pointer values?

Comment: I'm not sure, because it's software build with 5k source files, as we are trying to get the coverage gaps, we have very less idea about the software code.

Comment: Have you checked the lcov zero coverage capture data option: ```-i```? Refer [here](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/lcov.1.php) for more details. Even I was getting varying results on the capture information depending on the test scenario execution you might see different number of files in your final report.